# null check / optional chaining for array contents?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

we're all familiar with the

`tune?.image`

type of null checks in Typescript [optional chaining docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

but what's the best practice for checking this with an array value?

`tune.images?[0]`

will not work. I often use:

`tune.images ? tune.images[0] : null`

actually I think this is the better example:

`tune.images.length`

where `tune?.images?.length` will fail.

the best alternate I've found is:

`if (!tune.images || tune?.images?.length < 1) {`

but it seems overly verbose. Better ideas?

Comment: You are missing a dot: `tune.images?.[0]`, see [optional chaining with expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions)

Comment: The documentation you linked to mentions how to do this with bracket notation. But this is an ECMAScript feature anyway, so the JavaScript documentation of the real thing is [on MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/md3eC.png

Comment: clarified - reading a property like `length` seems to be the more problematic